# Junit testing for a class with strings

Tags: junit

```
//DOC Datatype Constants
public enum DocDatatype {

    PROFILE("Profile"),

    SUPPORT_DETAIL("SupportDetail"),

    MISC_PAGE("MiscPage"),

String name;

    DocDatatype(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    // the identifierMethod
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }

    // the valueOfMethod
    public static DocDatatype fromString(String value) {
        for (DocDatatype type : DocDatatype.values()) {
            if (type.getName().equals(value))
                return type;
        }

        throw new java.lang.IllegalArgumentException(value
                + " is Not valid dmDataType");
    }
}
```

I have written the junit test case in this way. Whether it is right way to write or wrong way...?

```
public class DocDatatypeTest {

    private static final Log logger = LogFactory
            .getLog(TreeConstantTest.class);

    @Test
    public void testDocDatatypeFromName()
    {
        DocDatatype d= DocDatatype.fromString("Profile");

        assertTrue((d.toString().compareToIgnoreCase("PROFILE") == 0));

    }

    @Test
    public void testDocDatatypeFromName1()
    {
        DocDatatype d = DocDatatype.fromString("SupportDetail");
        assertTrue((d.toString().compareToIgnoreCase("SUPPORT_DETAIL") == 0 ));
    }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things here:

- Remove the logger from the test.  A test should pass or fail, no need for logging
- Don't use assertTrue for this.  If the test fails it will give you no information about /why/ it failed.

I would change this to

```
@Test
public void testDocDatatypeFromName()
{
    DocDatatype actualDocType = DocDatatype.fromString("Profile");
    assertSame(DocDataType.PROFILE, actualDocType);
}
```

If you really want to assert that value of the toString then do this

```
@Test
public void testDocDatatypeFromName()
{
    DocDatatype d= DocDatatype.fromString("Profile");
    assertEquals("Profile", d.toString());
}
```

- You're missing tests for when the lookup doesn't match anything
- I wouldn't even write these tests as I see them adding no value whatsoever.  The code that *uses* the enums should have the tests, not these.
- Your tests are named very badly.  There's no need to start a test with `test` and the fact you add a "1" to the end of the second test should tell you something.  Test names should focus on *action* and *behaviour*.  If you want to read more about this, get the December issue of [JAX Magazine](http://jaxenter.com/jax-magazine) which has a snippet about naming from my forthcoming book about testing.

Comment: @Test
public void testDocDatatypeFromName()
{
    DocDatatype actualDocType = DocDatatype.fromString("Profile");
    assertSame(DocDataType.PROFILE, actualDocType);
}

Comment: Its showing me a error as DocDataType cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: Sorry, should be DocDatatype, note the capitalisation